Why do Blazor render fragments render out of sequence with surrounding HTML components?
I have a simple Blazor project that contains a home page and a reference to Razor component library. The component contains a RenderFrament that is inserted in a <table> element, but the resulting HTML does not reflect this.
The project has a home page:
@page "/"

<Grid Data="_data">
    <Rows Context="context">
        @context.Name
    </Rows>
</Grid>

@code {
    private List<Item> _data = null!;

    private class Item
    {
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

        public static Item Placeholder() => new() { Description = "foo", Name = "bar" };
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _data = [Item.Placeholder(), Item.Placeholder()];
    }
}

And a reference to a Razor component library with the following files:
Grid.razor
@typeparam T

<table>
    @if (Data is not null)
    {
        @foreach (T row in Data)
        {
            @Rows(row)
        }
    }
</table>

Grid.razor.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public partial class Grid<T> : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public List<T>? Data { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public required RenderFragment<T> Rows { get; set; }
}

The resulting HTML is
<body>
    barbar
    <table></table>
</body>

Why is barbar not contained in the <table> component?


Why do Blazor render fragments render out of sequence with surrounding HTML components?

They don't.  I copied and pasted your code into a Blazor Server Project [Interactivity: Global] and the resultant Html looks like this.
So what is different between the code you've shown in the question and the actual code?
<article class="content px-4" b-ihgnx5p0nt="">
  <!--!-->
  <!--!-->
  <table>
    barbar
  </table>
</article>



It appears that I needed to explicitly apply the interactive server render mode to fix my problem. Why is it though that using static rendering causes this issue?
